# Is anybody able to translate this math scheme in Latex?

Tags: tikz-cd

is anybody able to put this in LateX?

[image]

I am a LateX user, but I have never used that mach math and this is for a friend.

Comment: try searching the docs for `tikz` or commutative diagrams ie `tikz-cd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pasting here a basic solution using `tikz-cd`. I strongly recommend you delve into the package docs to find out more since this is kind of page 1

```
     \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}
  A\times B\arrow[r,"f"] \arrow{d}[left]{\varphi_{AB}}&C\\
  A\otimes B\arrow{ur}[near start, right,inner sep=1em]{\phi} &\\
  \end{tikzcd}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for getting `\\ ` at the ends of the lines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it was easier this time

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions: one with `pstricks`, and one with `tikz-cd` (simplified syntax):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{pstricks}: \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.2, linewidth=0.5pt, nodesep=2pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=1cm, shortput=nab, linejoin=1}
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\begin{psmatrix}
  %%%nodes
  A \times B& C \\%
  A\otimes B%%%
  %%% arrows
  \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\naput{f} \ncline{1,1}{2,1}\nbput{\varphi_{\!{}_{AB}}}\\
  \ncline{2,1}{1,2}\nbput[nrot=:U]{\phi}
\end{psmatrix}
\]

With \texttt{tikz-cd}:

 \[ \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5cm, row sep=1cm, arrows={-stealth}]
A\times B\rar{f}\dar[swap]{\varphi_{\!{}_{AB}}} & C \\%
A\otimes B \urar[swap,]{\phi}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the tiki-cd version, in place of `C` should be `A \otimes B`.

Comment: Oh! Bad copy-paste. Thanks for pointing itl I'll fix that in a moment.